# Get data from future func and change the object

Tags: flutter, dart, datepicker, widget

Good day!
I have a class ToDoItem

```
    class ToDoItem with ChangeNotifier {
  final String id;
  final DateTime creationDate;
  final DateTime doingDate;
  final String text;
  final Color color;

  ToDoItem({this.id, this.creationDate, this.doingDate, this.text, this.color});

    }
```

Then I have a DatePicker

```
class _TopWithDateAndOptionState extends State<TopWithDateAndOption> {
  var finaldate;
  void callDatePicker() async {
    var order = await getDate().then(
      (value) => print("VAL = ${value}"),
    );
    // setState(() {
    //   finaldate = order;
    //   print("pickeddate = ${finaldate}");
    // });
  }

  Future<DateTime> getDate() {
    // Imagine that this function is
    // more complex and slow.
    return showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
      firstDate: DateTime(2018),
      lastDate: DateTime(2030),
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
        return Theme(
          data: ThemeData.light(),
          child: child,
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

And at the end I get object of ToDoItem class by Provider.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final todoItem = Provider.of<ToDoItem>(context);
```

So the question is how to change the **doingDate** in object **ToDoItem** with new value of **finaldate**?
How to check out if this variable was already changed by new data from DataPicker? Should I use any listener or something simpler?

Comment: Hi Vladimir, I think you can use the map method to change doingDate
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/map.html

Comment: Thanks! I will write a code to change the doingDate. Problem is how to let this func of changing to know that finalDate was changed by Datepicker? For instance, I click choose a new date in DatePicker, confirm it, and after that my changing function must know that is time to change doingDate.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was the stateful widget. I've changed it to stateless and it worked/